# Adjusting tolerance of topology checking using QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, topology

I have a problem, the topology checker shows very tiny overlaps between polygons (under 0,000001 qm). For our project we just want to see detect the relevant overlaps, which are more than 0,01 qm.

Where can I adjust the tolerance of the topology checker tool?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do - but when speaking about topology, than overlap is overlap - no matter how small as it can affect geoprocessing.

Comment: I want to detect overlaps that are bigger than 0,01 qm.

Comment: Just as an idea: use overlapping Geoprocessing Tool and in the resultin layer calculate the area, then select all > 0.01.

Comment: You may use a tool like "Snap geometries to layer" or equivalent to remove small overlap before using the topology checker.