# Increase tolerance of QGIS processing tools

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, differences, tolerance

I have 2 line layers in QGIS 3.22.0 and I

1. create a 10cm-buffer around line layer A (red)
2. perform a difference of line layer B (blue) with the buffer of layer A (light red)

[image]

As a result I get 1 feature, which is around 5 meters long. But additionally to this I get 3 more features. They are so small I can't see them on the map canvas no matter how far I zoom in and use "pan to selected feature" tool. Therefore I computed the length in UTM with 20 decimal places. It turns out, the length of the 3 other line features is VEEERY small: 0,0000000006851682540200000489 meters which should be 0,01 Nanometers when I am right.

[image]

How do I make sure, I only get the 1 line feature and not the other 3 tiny features which are shorter than 1 nanometer?

I know I could do a filter by length but that doesn't help us much.

We deal here with a general problem. I have to do validity checks of data layers with several thousand features. And I repeatedly run into these "tolerance" problems as I already posted here two months ago: [Adjusting tolerance of topology checking using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/410849/adjusting-tolerance-of-topology-checking-using-qgis)

Comment: Why wouldn't a filter on length afterwards help? Just delete all features less than 1 cm.

Comment: Because I desribe a general problem, that occurs when I perform clips, differences, etc. The "sensitivity" of QGIS is too high and it complicates the geoprocessing a lot. I don't want to get lines , that are smaller than 0,1 Nanometers (!). This makes validity checking far too cumbersome.

Comment: Is it an issue with sensitivity, or an issue with your data quality?

Comment: @EnzoBaldini - I was unable to replicate your issue. Consider closing this question, and opening a bug report for QGIS, as it's probably more appropriately investigated by QGIS developers.